# How to plot huge dask dataframe box plot preferably holoviews?

Tags: python, dask, holoviews

How to plot huge Dask Dataframe box plot?

I need to plot DASK dataframe, I do:

```
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib')

d = dd.read_parquet(dataset_dir+'/train/date*/*.parquet', 
engine='pyarrow', columns=numeric_columns[:3]).fillna(0)

hv.BoxWhisker(data=d, datatype=['dask'])
```

and give:

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/holoviews/core/data/interface.py in initialize(cls, eltype, data, kdims, vdims, datatype)
    247                                   % (intfc.__name__, e))
    248                 error = ' '.join([error, priority_error])
--> 249             raise DataError(error)
    250 
    251         return data, interface, dims, extra_kws

DataError: None of the available storage backends were able to support the supplied data format. DaskInterface raised following error:

 unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to specify the datatype in most cases, it will automatically infer that you are supplying a dask dataframe. I can't quite tell where the problem is, but I think it's that you need to tell it which column to display. HoloViews generally assumes a flat (rather than a wide) data format, which means that it's expecting a single value column, which can be "faceted" by the other columns. If you're dealing with "wide" data, i.e. you want a plot comparing the distribution of values of the three columns I'd suggest you use [hvPlot](https://hvplot.pyviz.org).

Using hvPlot it should be as simple as:

```
import hvplot.dask
d.hvplot.box()
```

That all being said, dask integration for box plots isn't optimized for dask yet so it will load each column into memory in its entirety. This should eventually be addressed as part of [this issue](https://github.com/pyviz/holoviews/issues/2786).